# Java Rest API doesn't parse request body into java entity

Tags: java, rest, class, swagger

I am trying to use a java class as post body type, but if I log its contents it gives null, although it seems to know what the size of the array is..
The logs I am getting from running this:
From the service:

```
 size in Service: 1, null = null
```

From the controller:

```
size: 1, null = null
```

The json I send as body (which is the default swagger gives):

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "value": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Service:

```
@POST
    @Path("/service/run/sequence/macless")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Run the install, validate or uninstall sequence for a service and get all the return parameters of that sequence")
    @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK")})
    public ServiceProvisioningData runServiceSequenceMacless(
            @ApiParam(value = "The identifier, internally known as the lineID, that is configured on the device", required = true) @QueryParam("lineID") String lineID,
            @ApiParam(value = "The service name", required = true) @QueryParam("serviceName") String serviceName,
            @ApiParam(value = "The sequence you want to run", required = true) @QueryParam("sequenceName") Sequence sequenceName,
            @ApiParam(value = "The input parameters you want to overwrite for this sequence", required = false) ProvisioningData inputs
    ) throws ServiceException {
        LOG.error("size in Service: " + inputs.getRecords().size() + ", " + inputs.toString());
        return restApiController.runServiceSequenceMacless(lineID, serviceName, sequenceName.toString(), inputs);
    }
```

controller:

```
public ServiceProvisioningData runServiceSequenceMacless(String lineID, String serviceName, String sequenceName, ProvisioningData inputs) throws ServiceException {
        // FIRST INSERT THE INPUT PARAMETERS FOR THE DEVICE
        LOG.error("size: " + inputs.getRecords().size() + ", " + inputs.toString());
        inputs.getRecords().forEach(record -> {
            try {
                createInputParamValueForServiceForDeviceMacless(lineID, serviceName, record.getName(), record.getValue());
            } catch (ServiceException e) {
                LOG.error("Exception in adding input parameters macless: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        });
...
```

ProvisioningData:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "provisioningdata")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "records" })
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ProvisioningData {

    public static void registerToContextProvider(){
        try {
            CustomContextProvider.registerClass(ProvisioningData.class);
            CustomContextProvider.registerArray("records");
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.error("Could not register ProvisioningData: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /** The properties. */
    private List<ProvisioningRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Instantiates a new ProvisioningData.
     */
    public ProvisioningData(List<ProvisioningRecord> records) {
        this.records = records;
    }
    /**
     * Instantiates a new ProvisioningData.
     */
    public ProvisioningData() {
    }

    /**
     * Gets the records.
     *
     * @return the records
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "records")
    public List<ProvisioningRecord> getRecords() {
        return records;
    }

    public void setRecords(List<ProvisioningRecord> res) {
        this.records = res;
    }

    public void addEntry(ScriptVariableValueRecord rec) {
        records.add(new ProvisioningRecord(rec));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder recs = new StringBuilder();
        for (ProvisioningRecord record : records){
            recs.append(record.getName()).append(" = ").append(record.getValue()).append(", ");
        }
        return recs.toString();
    }
}
```

ProvisioningRecord:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "record")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "name", "value" })
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ProvisioningRecord {

    public static void registerToContextProvider(){
        try {
            CustomContextProvider.registerClass(ProvisioningRecord.class);
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.error("Could not register ProvisioningRecord: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /** The name. */
    private String name;

    /** The value. */
    private String value;

    public ProvisioningRecord() {
    }

    public ProvisioningRecord(ScriptVariableValueRecord record) {
        name = record.getName();
        value = record.getValue();
    }
    public ProvisioningRecord(ScriptVariableValueModel model) {
        name = model.getName();
        value = model.getValue();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the variable name.
     *
     * @return the variable name
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the variable value.
     *
     * @return the variable value
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried annotating the `inputs` parameter with `@RequestBody`?

Comment: That annotation is not available to me.. Annotations that I can use come from io.swagger.annotations, is there maybe an equivalent for this?